# Featured image for links and categories

Tags: categories, links, media-library, post-thumbnails

Is there a ready plugin or solution for implementing Featured Image function to Categories and Links?

At Pages and Posts I use the feature image as a background image, using the full size original image, and I'd like to achieve the same, meaning I'd like to have featured full size image for categories.

With Links, I'd like to attach an upload image to them, probably with auto-resize ability with different size to the default media size.

Are there solutions already done to achieve these?

Thanks,
cadeyrn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to use two plugins: [Link Image Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/links-image-gallery/) and [Category Meta plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-category-meta/) although I had to tweak one of them.

They both use the media gallery to select picture, but if both very active, Link Image Gallery disabled the return function of Category Meta plugin, so I added a check in Link Image Gallery's main function: "if (strsrt($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'links.php'))", and now they both work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are no afraid of code , take a look at http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/taxonomy-meta-script-for-wordpress.html

it had a great class to add "meta fields" for taxonomies (including categories) and a very simple way to implement the built in media uploader to a custom field in the edit category screen.

> Uploaded images' ID are saved as a field with multiple values. Each uploaded image is treated as an attachment. This means it has all sizes that defined in Media section or in your theme functions.php file. So, you can use some built-in functions to get image URL, image size, etc.